# Partitions of unity subordinate to a cover vs non-zero points lie in cover

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, not paracompact but possibly Hausdorff if necessary. Suppose I have a partition of unity $\phi_i$ and a locally finite open covering $U_i\subset X$ so that $\phi_i^{-1}(0,1]\subset U_i$.

But this does not imply $\mathrm{supp}(\phi_i)\subset U_i$. Can I find a partition of unity and a locally finite open covering so that this condition is fulfilled? Probably from modification of the given partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a partition of unity subordinate to $(U_i)_i$. Such a family indeed exists, and is induced by the given family $\phi_i$. To show this, you can use lemma (13.1.4) in tom Dieck's [*Algebraic Topology*](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/diecktop.pdf):

> **Lemma.** Let $(f_j: X \to [0,\infty) \mid j \in J)$ be a family of continuous functions such that $U = (f^{-1}(0,\infty) \mid j \in J)$ is a locally finite covering of $X$. Then $U$ is numerable and has, in particular, a shrinking.

In tom Dieck's terminology, $U$ being *numerable* means that it has a *numeration*, that is, a subordinate partition of unity.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!